# Sequelize order by included model's existence

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

```
const products = await TrProduct.findAll({
      where: {
        userId: userId,
      },
      offset: (page - 1) * 20,
      limit: 20,
      attributes: ['id'],
      include: {
        model: TrLine,
        limit: 1,
        required: false
      },
      order: [[TrLine, 'id', 'ASC', 'NULLS LAST']]
    });
```

I have a query like this. TrProduct and TrLine models are associated. But not all TrProduct rows have a corresponding TrLine row.

I have tried but I couldn't solve it. I want to order by TrLine rows' existence which means that TrProduct rows with a corresponding TrLine rows will be prioritized.

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your question it looks like you want the records with some `TrLine`s will be ordered first and records without a `TrLine` will be ordered second.

You can acheive this by doing some sort criteria as follows:

- If there's a `TrLine`, sort it first.
- If not, sort it second.

#### code:

```js
  order: [[Sequelize.literal('CASE WHEN "CHANGE_IT"."id" IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END'), 'ASC'], [Sequelize.col('CHANGE_IT.id'), 'ASC', 'NULLS LAST']],
```

Comment: it says "missing FROM-clause entry for table "tr_lines""

Comment: I've updated the code, try it again and lemme know
- change the `CHANGE_IT` to the corresponding `TrLine` model name  that was generated by sequelize.

Comment: const product = await TrProduct.findAll({
      where: {
        userId: userId,
      },
      offset: (page - 1) * 20,
      limit: 20,
      attributes: ['id'],
      include: {
        model: TrLines,
        limit: 1,
        required: false
      },
      order: [[Sequelize.literal('CASE WHEN "tr_lines"."id" IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END'), 'ASC'], [Sequelize.col('tr_lines.id'), 'ASC', 'NULLS LAST']]
    }); again the same error....